# How to deserialize a json with type information to a Map<String, Object>?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, polymorphism, deserialization

I have a class `SomeClass`:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public String someString = "SOME-STRING-VALUE";

    public Date someDate = new Date();
}
```

My goal is to create a `Map<String, Object>` which contains the member names of `SomeClass` as key and their values as the value in the map for a given instance of `SomeClass`

For this I am using Jackson as below:

```
SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass();

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(someObject);    // serialize object
System.out.println(jsonString);    // {"someString":"SOME-STRING-VALUE","someDate":1500138786720}

Map<String, Object> objectMap = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);    // deserialize back to Map instead of SomeClass
objectMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " : " + v + " : " + v.getClass()));
// This prints:
// someString : SOME-STRING-VALUE : class java.lang.String
// someDate : 1500138786720 : class java.lang.Long
```

So I am serializing the object to `jsonString` using object-mapper and then to create the required map, I am deserializing the `jsonString` back to a `Map`.

The problem here is that the `Date` field is being serialized as a primitive long value and while deserializing back it is getting deserialized as a `Long` instead of `Date`, as I am deserialzing it to `Object`. Had I been doing the deserialization back to `SomeClass` the `Long` value would have been converted to the relevant `Date` value. But for my case, while deserializing, the `mapper` doesn't know what was the actual type of `someDate` before deserialization and thus `someDate` is being deserialized as `Long` itself in the `objectMap`.

It seems there is a way indeed to let the mapper know what was the type of a given field in the `jsonString` before serialization by embedding the type information in the `jsonString` using [Jackson Polymorphic Type Handling](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization). For that I enabled default typing before writing the `jsonString` by using:

`mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);`

The `jsonString` that I get now is:

`["some.package.name.here.SomeClass",{"someString":"SOME-STRING-VALUE","someDate":["java.util.Date",1500140185993]}]`

So the `jsonString` now contains the type of `someDate` field. But I am facing difficulty to read back this `jsonString` having type information within it to my `objectMap`. I am getting the exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class some.package.name.here.SomeClass
>   not subtype of [map type; class java.util.Map, [simple type, class
>   java.lang.Object] -> [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]

Do I need to change the line `Map<String, Object> objectMap = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);` to something else to let the `mapper` know that the string it is going to read is not a normal string, but a string with type information embedded in it. Shouldn't the mapper be already knowing this, as the mapper object we are using to read the `jsonString` is the very same mapper object that wrote it?

All the examples I found are following the inheritance hierarchy example where while reading they will just pass the BaseClass, but I am not able to figure out what shall I do for my case.

How do I convert the `someDate` field back to `Date` from `Long` while putting it in a map having `Object` type of values?